# DevExpress Refreshing gridcontrol from another form in vb.net not working

Tags: vb.net, winforms, devexpress

I Have problem with gridcontrol that doesn't refresh after insert data from another form
i was trying with this

```
GridControl1.Refresh()
GridView1.RefreshData()
GridControl1.RefreshDataSource()
```

all this not working

im using this code

```
Private Sub Save_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Save.Click
        Dim Cmd As New SqlCommand
        With Cmd
            .Connection = Con
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .CommandText =
                "Insert into Customers(CustomerId,CustName,CustAddress,CustActivite,CustTel,CustEmail,CustRC,CustNIF,CustArt,Forhim,Athim)values(@CustomerId,@CustName,@CustAddress,@CustActivite,@CustTel,@CustEmail,@CustRC,@CustNIF,@CustArt,@Forhim,@Athim)"
            .Parameters.Clear()
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("CustomerId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TxtCLCode.Text
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("CustName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = TxtClName.Text

        End With
        If Con.State = 1 Then Close()
        Con.Open()
        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Con.Close()
        MsgBox("تم الحفظ بنجاح", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "حفظ")
        ClearControls()
        ClientFrm.SqlDataSource2.Fill()
        ClientFrm.GridControl1.Refresh()
        ClientFrm.GridView1.RefreshData()
        ClientFrm.GridControl1.RefreshDataSource()
        TxtCLCode.Text = GetMaxID("Customers", "CustomerId").ToString
        'FournisseurFrm.SqlDataSource2.Fill()
        'FournisseurFrm.ShowDialog()

        Cmd = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you close your connection:

> Con.Close()

I guess you want to refresh other grid by execute select from database. So how you wanna get anything from database when you close connection?
I think it's imposbile.
Try:

```
If Con.State = 1 Then Close()
Con.Open()
Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
ClearControls()
ClientFrm.SqlDataSource2.Fill()
ClientFrm.GridControl1.Refresh()
ClientFrm.GridView1.RefreshData()
ClientFrm.GridControl1.RefreshDataSource()
Con.Close()
```

If you use other connection to refreshing data in this grid, check connection state. Maybe this is a problem.

Comment: I use your code but its the same problem

Comment: Okay, so idk how I can help you.